# Receiving "expected expression before" Error When Using A Struct

Tags: c

I'm in the process of creating a simple 2D game engine in C with a group of friends at school. I'd like to write this engine in an Object-Oriented way, using `structs` as classes, function pointers as methods, etc. To emulate standard OOP syntax, I created a `create()` function which allocates space in memory for the object. I'm in the process of testing it out, and I'm receiving an error. Here is my code for two files that I'm using to test:

**test.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        typedef struct
        {
                int i;
        } Class;

        Class *test = (Class*) create(Class);
        test->i = 1;

        printf("The value of \"test\" is: %i\n", test->i);

        return 0;
}
```

**utils.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "utils.h"

void* create(const void* class)
{
        void *obj = (void*) malloc(sizeof(class));
        if (obj == 0)
        {
                printf("Error allocating memory.\n");
                return (int*) -1;
        }
        else {
                return obj;
        }
}

void destroy(void* object)
{
        free(object);
}
```

The `utils.h` file simply holds prototypes for the `create()` and `destroy()` functions.

When I execute `gcc test.c utils.c -o test`, I'm receiving this error message:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:10:32: error: expected expression before 'Class'
```

I know it has something to do with my `typedef` at the beginning, and how I'm probably not using proper syntax. But I have no idea what that proper syntax is. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you want to really make it object-oriented, why not use C++ instead?

Comment: You're casting a `void *` to `void *`. It really makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code make no sense in this area

```
Class *test = (Class*) create(Class);
```

`Class` is a type name. Why are you trying to pass it as an argument to `create`? You cannot use type names as a function arguments in C.

Your `create` function seems to expect some sort of pointer as an argument. The purpose of that pointer is entirely unclear to me, but the bottom line here is that type name `Class` cannot be used as an argument here.

Inside your `create` you use `sizeof(class)` as the amount of memory to allocate. This `sizeof(class)` will simply evaluate to a pointer size, which is absolutely not what you need.

Basically, you need to rethink what you are trying to do and do it from scratch. I'd suggest reading so book on C first. What you have now is just... random.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Class *test = (Class*) create(Class);
```

Shouldn't it be

```
Class *test = (Class*) create(sizeof(Class));
```

instead?

Notice that `class` is a reversed C++ keyword:

```
void* create(const void* class)
```

**EDIT**
You could should be:

```
void* create(unsigned sz)
{
        void *obj = (void*) malloc(sz);
        if (obj == 0)
        {
                printf("Error allocating memory.\n");
        }
        return obj;
}

void destroy(void* obj)
{
        free(obj);
}
```

Usage:

```
  Class *test = (Class*) create(sizeof(Class));
```

Comment: He wants to allocate memory for the structure, and he is doing it wrong. He either must return the allocated block of memory OR pass the structure as an argument.

Comment: No. It should be `Class *test = create(sizeof(Class));`

Comment: Your version of the create function is C++, this question is tagged as C. But what is problematic, is that dangerous cast of the return type of malloc.